# Kolla-Ansible deployment fails on Ubuntu 22.04 while "Waiting for nova-compute services to register themselves"

Tags: openstack, kolla-ansible

**Problem Statement:**
Kolla Ansible installation fails on "deploy" play with the below errors ('Errors' Section).

**About the Deployment:**

- Lab Openstack deployment using Kolla Ansible
- 1 Controller, 2 Compute nodes, 1 Block Storage node using LVM / Cinder Volumes
- All nodes running Ubuntu 22.04
- "Bootstrap-servers" and "prechecks" plays succeed. The Deploy fails

**Troubleshooting done:**

- https://lists.openstack.org/pipermail/openstack-discuss/2022-September/030641.html
- This link seems to match my exact issue.
- However, I'm not trying to do SSL on HA Proxy.
- Deployment fails with the same error irrespective of whether "enable_haproxy" is kept on or off.
- Deployment fails with the same error irrespective of whether the "external fqdn" and "external vip" are commented or not / commented.
- My globals.yml output below.

**Errors:**

```
TASK [nova-cell : Waiting for nova-compute services to register themselves] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [compute2]
skipping: [controller]
fatal: [compute1 -> controller]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '(nova_compute_services.stdout | from_json | map(attribute='Host') | list) is superset(expected_compute_service_hosts)' failed. The error was: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}

TASK [nova-cell : Fail if nova-compute service failed to register] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [compute2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'any_failed_services or (nova_compute_registration_fatal | bool and\n failed_compute_service_hosts | length > 0)' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (any_failed_services or (nova_compute_registration_fatal | bool and\n failed_compute_service_hosts | length > 0)): {{ ansible_facts.nodename in failed_compute_service_hosts or\n   (ansible_facts.hostname ~ \"-ironic\") in failed_compute_service_hosts }}: {{ expected_compute_service_hosts | difference(nova_compute_service_hosts) | list }}: {{ hostvars[all_computes_in_batch[0]].nova_compute_services.stdout |\n   from_json |\n   map(attribute='Host') |\n   list }}: Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({{ hostvars[all_computes_in_batch[0]].nova_compute_services.stdout |\n   from_json |\n   map(attribute='Host') |\n   list }}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not AnsibleUndefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/usr/local/share/kolla-ansible/ansible/roles/nova-cell/tasks/wait_discover_computes.yml': line 45, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    # that failed to register.\n    - name: Fail if nova-compute service failed to register\n      ^ here\n"}
fatal: [controller]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'any_failed_services or (nova_compute_registration_fatal | bool and\n failed_compute_service_hosts | length > 0)' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (any_failed_services or (nova_compute_registration_fatal | bool and\n failed_compute_service_hosts | length > 0)): {{ ansible_facts.nodename in failed_compute_service_hosts or\n   (ansible_facts.hostname ~ \"-ironic\") in failed_compute_service_hosts }}: {{ expected_compute_service_hosts | difference(nova_compute_service_hosts) | list }}: {{ hostvars[all_computes_in_batch[0]].nova_compute_services.stdout |\n   from_json |\n   map(attribute='Host') |\n   list }}: Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({{ hostvars[all_computes_in_batch[0]].nova_compute_services.stdout |\n   from_json |\n   map(attribute='Host') |\n   list }}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not AnsibleUndefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/usr/local/share/kolla-ansible/ansible/roles/nova-cell/tasks/wait_discover_computes.yml': line 45, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    # that failed to register.\n    - name: Fail if nova-compute service failed to register\n      ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
block1                     : ok=31   changed=5    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=9    rescued=0    ignored=0
compute1                   : ok=37   changed=5    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=16   rescued=0    ignored=0
compute2                   : ok=37   changed=5    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=16   rescued=0    ignored=0
controller                 : ok=163  changed=15   unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=93   rescued=0    ignored=0
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**globals.yml output:**

```
zindagi@deployment:~$ grep -v '^\s*$\|^\s*\#' /etc/kolla/globals.yml
---
workaround_ansible_issue_8743: yes
config_strategy: "COPY_ALWAYS"
kolla_base_distro: "ubuntu"
openstack_release: "master"
kolla_internal_vip_address: "10.0.0.10"
kolla_internal_fqdn: "{{ kolla_internal_vip_address }}"
kolla_external_vip_address: "{{ kolla_internal_vip_address }}"
kolla_external_fqdn: "{{ kolla_external_vip_address }}"
network_interface: "eth1"
neutron_external_interface: "eth2"
neutron_plugin_agent: "openvswitch"
keepalived_virtual_router_id: "51"
enable_openstack_core: "yes"
enable_glance: "{{ enable_openstack_core | bool }}"
enable_haproxy: "no"
enable_keystone: "{{ enable_openstack_core | bool }}"
enable_neutron: "{{ enable_openstack_core | bool }}"
enable_cinder: "yes"
enable_cinder_backup: "no"
enable_cinder_backend_iscsi: "{{ enable_cinder_backend_lvm | bool }}"
enable_cinder_backend_lvm: "yes"
enable_heat: "{{ enable_openstack_core | bool }}"
enable_horizon: "{{ enable_openstack_core | bool }}"
enable_openvswitch: "{{ enable_neutron | bool and neutron_plugin_agent != 'linuxbridge' }}"
fernet_token_expiry: 86400
glance_backend_file: "yes"
cinder_volume_group: "cinder-volumes"
nova_compute_virt_type: "qemu"
nova_console: "novnc"
```

**UPDATE 1 - 8th May 4 PM IST:**

- I re-built this deployment from scratch.
- The previous deployment was on VirtualBox - switched over to ESXi 8.x (should not make a difference - still pointing it out)
- Increased specs of the VMs being used
- This time i used "rocky" as the "base distro" in "globals.yml".
- Some more changes to my globals.yml (below)
- This time the deployment DID NOT fail on nova-compute services failing to register. However, it broken on a **different error message**:

**ERROR:**

```
RUNNING HANDLER [iscsi : Restart tgtd container] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [kolla-block1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "'Traceback (most recent call last):\\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py\", line 268, in _raise_for_status\\n    response.raise_for_status()\\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py\", line 943, in raise_for_status\\n    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)\\nrequests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.42/images/create?tag=master-rocky-9&fromImage=quay.io%2Fopenstack.kolla%2Ftgtd\\n\\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\\n\\nTraceback (most recent call last):\\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_y2hdgwrz/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py\", line 406, in main\\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_y2hdgwrz/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/kolla_docker_worker.py\", line 370, in recreate_or_restart_container\\n    self.start_container()\\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_y2hdgwrz/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/kolla_docker_worker.py\", line 388, in start_container\\n    self.pull_image()\\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_y2hdgwrz/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/kolla_docker_worker.py\", line 211, in pull_image\\n    json.loads(line.strip().decode(\\'utf-8\\')) for line in self.dc.pull(\\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/api/image.py\", line 430, in pull\\n    self._raise_for_status(response)\\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py\", line 270, in _raise_for_status\\n    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)\\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/docker/errors.py\", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception\\n    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)\\ndocker.errors.NotFound: 404 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.42/images/create?tag=master-rocky-9&fromImage=quay.io%2Fopenstack.kolla%2Ftgtd: Not Found (\"manifest for quay.io/openstack.kolla/tgtd:master-rocky-9 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown\")\\n'"}
```

**Revised globals.yml**

```
zindagi@kolla-deployment:~$ grep -v '^\s*$\|^\s*\#' /etc/kolla/globals.yml
---
workaround_ansible_issue_8743: yes
kolla_base_distro: "rocky"
kolla_internal_vip_address: "192.168.1.250"
network_interface: "eth1"
neutron_external_interface: "eth2"
neutron_plugin_agent: "openvswitch"
enable_openstack_core: "yes"
enable_haproxy: "yes"
enable_cinder: "yes"
enable_cinder_backup: "no"
enable_cinder_backend_lvm: "yes"
enable_openvswitch: "{{ enable_neutron | bool and neutron_plugin_agent != 'linuxbridge' }}"
fernet_token_expiry: 86400
glance_backend_file: "yes"
cinder_volume_group: "cinder-volumes"
nova_compute_virt_type: "qemu"
nova_console: "novnc"
```

**UPDATE 1 - 8th May 5:30 PM:**

- I believe this is resolved now.

  - Changed "base distro" back to Ubuntu
  - Changed enable_cinder_backend_iscsi back to "yes"
  - The biggest change i made was changing the release from "master" to "zed".

**Output of the "deploy" play of Kolla**

```
PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
kolla-block1               : ok=34   changed=23   unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=11   rescued=0    ignored=0
kolla-compute1             : ok=69   changed=43   unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=51   rescued=0    ignored=0
kolla-compute2             : ok=64   changed=43   unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=50   rescued=0    ignored=0
kolla-controller           : ok=323  changed=215  unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=242  rescued=0    ignored=1
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**Final globals.yml file:**

```
root@kolla-deployment:/home/zindagi# grep -v '^\s*$\|^\s*\#' /etc/kolla/globals.yml
---
workaround_ansible_issue_8743: yes
kolla_base_distro: "ubuntu"
kolla_internal_vip_address: "192.168.1.250"
network_interface: "eth1"
neutron_external_interface: "eth2"
neutron_plugin_agent: "openvswitch"
enable_openstack_core: "yes"
enable_haproxy: "yes"
enable_cinder: "yes"
enable_cinder_backup: "no"
enable_cinder_backend_iscsi: "yes"
enable_cinder_backend_lvm: "yes"
enable_openvswitch: "{{ enable_neutron | bool and neutron_plugin_agent != 'linuxbridge' }}"
fernet_token_expiry: 86400
glance_backend_file: "yes"
cinder_volume_group: "cinder-volumes"
nova_compute_virt_type: "qemu"
nova_console: "novnc"
```

**Outputs of docker ps -a from compute, controller and block/storage nodes:**

```
root@kolla-compute1:/home/zindagi# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                   COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS     NAMES
9f5130d4135b   quay.io/openstack.kolla/neutron-openvswitch-agent:master-ubuntu-jammy   "dumb-init --single-…"   3 minutes ago    Up 3 minutes (healthy)              neutron_openvswitch_agent
bdff1895f3af   quay.io/openstack.kolla/openvswitch-vswitchd:master-ubuntu-jammy        "dumb-init --single-…"   7 minutes ago    Up 7 minutes (healthy)              openvswitch_vswitchd
11ab834e7db4   quay.io/openstack.kolla/openvswitch-db-server:master-ubuntu-jammy       "dumb-init --single-…"   8 minutes ago    Up 8 minutes (healthy)              openvswitch_db
8f2734cb33f4   quay.io/openstack.kolla/nova-compute:master-ubuntu-jammy                "dumb-init --single-…"   9 minutes ago    Up 9 minutes (healthy)              nova_compute
2bbf5b3bbc35   quay.io/openstack.kolla/nova-libvirt:master-ubuntu-jammy                "dumb-init --single-…"   10 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes (healthy)             nova_libvirt
5b5281614f7d   quay.io/openstack.kolla/nova-ssh:master-ubuntu-jammy                    "dumb-init --single-…"   12 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes (healthy)             nova_ssh
32cf358b66de   quay.io/openstack.kolla/iscsid:master-ubuntu-jammy                      "dumb-init --single-…"   29 minutes ago   Up 29 minutes                       iscsid
2a5adf6983a4   quay.io/openstack.kolla/cron:master-ubuntu-jammy                        "dumb-init --single-…"   34 minutes ago   Up 34 minutes                       cron
a1a2ed0aa775   quay.io/openstack.kolla/kolla-toolbox:master-ubuntu-jammy               "dumb-init --single-…"   36 minutes ago   Up 35 minutes                       kolla_toolbox
4ed9854f1826   quay.io/openstack.kolla/fluentd:master-ubuntu-jammy                     "dumb-init --single-…"   37 minutes ago   Up 37 minutes                       fluentd
```

---

```
root@kolla-controller:/home/zindagi# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                   COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                        PORTS     NAMES
01750827b82b   quay.io/openstack.kolla/heat-engine:master-ubuntu-jammy                 "dumb-init --single-…"   About a minute ago   Up 57 seconds (healthy)                 heat_engine
dbba9ef19e19   quay.io/openstack.kolla/heat-api-cfn:master-ubuntu-jammy                "dumb-init --single-…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)             heat_api_cfn
c42514c10c14   quay.io/openstack.kolla/heat-api:master-ubuntu-jammy                    "dumb-init --single-…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)             heat_api
60fc15caabe4   quay.io/openstack.kolla/neutron-metadata-agent:master-ubuntu-jammy      "dumb-init --single-…"   3 minutes ago        Up 3 minutes (healthy)                  neutron_metadata_agent
affd17658759   quay.io/openstack.kolla/neutron-l3-agent:master-ubuntu-jammy            "dumb-init --single-…"   3 minutes ago        Up 3 minutes (healthy)                  neutron_l3_agent
cbb256538649   quay.io/openstack.kolla/neutron-dhcp-agent:master-ubuntu-jammy          "dumb-init --single-…"   4 minutes ago        Up 3 minutes (healthy)                  neutron_dhcp_agent
67d4c8f1b6b6   quay.io/openstack.kolla/neutron-openvswitch-agent:master-ubuntu-jammy   "dumb-init --single-…"   4 minutes ago        Up 4 minutes (healthy)                  neutron_openvswitch_agent
f34d7a7db2ee   quay.io/openstack.kolla/neutron-server:master-ubuntu-jammy              "dumb-init --single-…"   4 minutes ago        Up 4 minutes (healthy)                  neutron_server
3beefd2cd97a   quay.io/openstack.kolla/openvswitch-vswitchd:master-ubuntu-jammy        "dumb-init --single-…"   8 minutes ago        Up 8 minutes (healthy)                  openvswitch_vswitchd
83fc1eee9ae1   quay.io/openstack.kolla/openvswitch-db-server:master-ubuntu-jammy       "dumb-init --single-…"   8 minutes ago        Up 8 minutes (healthy)                  openvswitch_db
65992167e59a   quay.io/openstack.kolla/nova-novncproxy:master-ubuntu-jammy             "dumb-init --single-…"   14 minutes ago       Up 13 minutes (healthy)                 nova_novncproxy
cb58408a8728   quay.io/openstack.kolla/nova-conductor:master-ubuntu-jammy              "dumb-init --single-…"   14 minutes ago       Up 14 minutes (healthy)                 nova_conductor
6caa3a38cb4e   quay.io/openstack.kolla/nova-api:master-ubuntu-jammy                    "dumb-init --single-…"   15 minutes ago       Up 15 minutes (healthy)                 nova_api
7341fbb3ec59   quay.io/openstack.kolla/nova-scheduler:master-ubuntu-jammy              "dumb-init --single-…"   15 minutes ago       Up 15 minutes (healthy)                 nova_scheduler
ad3580d98c0b   quay.io/openstack.kolla/placement-api:master-ubuntu-jammy               "dumb-init --single-…"   18 minutes ago       Up 18 minutes (healthy)                 placement_api
0701d637d49d   quay.io/openstack.kolla/cinder-scheduler:master-ubuntu-jammy            "dumb-init --single-…"   21 minutes ago       Up 21 minutes (healthy)                 cinder_scheduler
6320ffe512fc   quay.io/openstack.kolla/cinder-api:master-ubuntu-jammy                  "dumb-init --single-…"   21 minutes ago       Up 21 minutes (healthy)                 cinder_api
ad0f2adb96a7   quay.io/openstack.kolla/glance-api:master-ubuntu-jammy                  "dumb-init --single-…"   23 minutes ago       Up 23 minutes (healthy)                 glance_api
f01034594a50   quay.io/openstack.kolla/keystone:master-ubuntu-jammy                    "dumb-init --single-…"   26 minutes ago       Up 26 minutes (healthy)                 keystone
2c4ed3eb1553   quay.io/openstack.kolla/keystone-fernet:master-ubuntu-jammy             "dumb-init --single-…"   26 minutes ago       Up 26 minutes (healthy)                 keystone_fernet
8b63d3416385   quay.io/openstack.kolla/keystone-ssh:master-ubuntu-jammy                "dumb-init --single-…"   26 minutes ago       Up 26 minutes (healthy)                 keystone_ssh
dc2ae69f6196   quay.io/openstack.kolla/rabbitmq:master-ubuntu-jammy                    "dumb-init --single-…"   29 minutes ago       Up 29 minutes (healthy)                 rabbitmq
8329d6a73929   quay.io/openstack.kolla/memcached:master-ubuntu-jammy                   "dumb-init --single-…"   30 minutes ago       Up 30 minutes (healthy)                 memcached
35acc9734a53   quay.io/openstack.kolla/mariadb-clustercheck:master-ubuntu-jammy        "dumb-init --single-…"   31 minutes ago       Up 31 minutes                           mariadb_clustercheck
8d94088d4c74   quay.io/openstack.kolla/mariadb-server:master-ubuntu-jammy              "dumb-init -- kolla_…"   31 minutes ago       Up 31 minutes (healthy)                 mariadb
4aebfdba90a9   quay.io/openstack.kolla/keepalived:master-ubuntu-jammy                  "dumb-init --single-…"   33 minutes ago       Up 33 minutes                           keepalived
123a4fc71aae   quay.io/openstack.kolla/haproxy:master-ubuntu-jammy                     "dumb-init --single-…"   33 minutes ago       Up 33 minutes (healthy)                 haproxy
7f6c2adc5e41   quay.io/openstack.kolla/cron:master-ubuntu-jammy                        "dumb-init --single-…"   35 minutes ago       Up 35 minutes                           cron
f1abce91f91a   quay.io/openstack.kolla/kolla-toolbox:master-ubuntu-jammy               "dumb-init --single-…"   35 minutes ago       Up 35 minutes                           kolla_toolbox
8056c8a6a470   quay.io/openstack.kolla/fluentd:master-ubuntu-jammy                     "dumb-init --single-…"   38 minutes ago       Up 37 minutes                           fluentd
```

---

```
root@kolla-block1:/home/zindagi# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                       COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS     NAMES
34eb37634e70   quay.io/openstack.kolla/cinder-volume:master-ubuntu-jammy   "dumb-init --single-…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes (healthy)             cinder_volume
140d5029b8c7   quay.io/openstack.kolla/tgtd:master-ubuntu-jammy            "dumb-init --single-…"   36 minutes ago   Up 36 minutes                       tgtd
3e7eb6195b1f   quay.io/openstack.kolla/iscsid:master-ubuntu-jammy          "dumb-init --single-…"   36 minutes ago   Up 36 minutes                       iscsid
a7e1464b43df   quay.io/openstack.kolla/cron:master-ubuntu-jammy            "dumb-init --single-…"   41 minutes ago   Up 41 minutes                       cron
837217ad632d   quay.io/openstack.kolla/kolla-toolbox:master-ubuntu-jammy   "dumb-init --single-…"   42 minutes ago   Up 41 minutes                       kolla_toolbox
f1cb0457cf12   quay.io/openstack.kolla/fluentd:master-ubuntu-jammy         "dumb-init --single-…"   44 minutes ago   Up 44 minutes                       fluentd
root@kolla-block1:/home/zindagi#
```

Comment: The last error message looks like a container registry issue (`http+docker://localhost/v1.42/images/create?tag=master-rocky-9&fromImage=quay.io%2Fopenstack.kolla%2Ftgtd: Not Found (\"manifest for quay.io/openstack.kolla/tgtd:master-rocky-9 not found`). I'm not sure how that's supposed to work, but either your local registry doesn't work or the image you're trying to pull does not exist (at least the tags).

Answer (score 0):

TASK [nova-cell : Waiting for nova-compute services to register themselves]

TASK [nova-cell : Fail if nova-compute service failed to register]

I'm having the same problem as you. Was the only solution to that method just changing the hypervisor from virtual box to vmware?

I'm trying to deploy on OpenStack nova.

Does this not meet the requirements of hypervisors in OpenStack?...@.@

-------march 6, 2024 updated-------------

I have solved the problem.
I configured a controller node with an openstack nova instance.

Control nodes configured in vm must be set to 'Allowed Address Pairs' for external_vip.

It is to set the packet to pass through even for virtual ports (IPs) that do not assign IP. After checking that, able to solve mariadb issues and Nova-cell related issues.

I hope the next developer who sees this post will refer to it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/576911)

Comment: edited my first write. thx